# is it ok to skip other authenticity steps if i include a signature?

Tags: java, java-security

i am using this:

```
        byte[] payload = objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(contents);
        Signature s = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        s.initSign(privKey);
        s.update(payload);
        byte[] sig = s.sign();
```

and then both byte arrays are concatenated. basically this should be enough to protect against ANY kind of corruption of the data, oth intentional and accidental.

eventually, things will be transferred in UDP packets, so i have no guarantees about integrity. but in normal operations, i don't really expect a lot of these.

the only reason i can think of to include another, cheaper hash of the entire thing is to be able to discard (accidentally) corrupted packets even before the signature has to be checked.

i cannot think of any other reason ... can you?

EDIT:

some more context. use-case wise, i am just exploring. the basic idea was to figure out encrypted file transfer in UDP. not necessarily because it makes a lot of sense, but rather because i can, and i have seen UDP-base file transfers, and i want to figure out the specific problems around this.

in my current scenario, the public keys of both sides are known to both parties. i was thinking that should probably be enough to initiate a session:

```
A  ---- i want to connect (+sig +nonce) -------------------> B
                                                             |
A  <--- ok, here's a symmetric session key (+sig) ---------- B
```

these two might just be encrypted with the public key of the opposite side, and the req / res might include a nonce and a timestamp to avoid replay attacks.

Comment: It doesn't seem to have protection against replay attacks

Comment: yes, i was wondering about that. how would you think i could go about this? i was thinking that i could add a timestamp, and verify that it is within a reasonable margin. i edited the question with more info.

Comment: If you go down that route, you should force clients to send a unique id with each message. Timestamps are unreliable. The good news is that you should do this anyway if you transfer your files in chunks.

Comment: Another way to avoid replay attacks is to use a challenge-response model. When the client sends a connection request, you should respond with a random number that the client then needs to send back as a confirmation that they have the client's private key. The random universe must of course be big enough to make guessing the response infeasible. This way all you reveal to a malicious replayer is a random number, and the only state change they can make you do is add a new entry to a map of challenges sent out. This can be exploited too though, so be careful.

Comment: But it's also useful to study existing methods like [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code), hand-rolled security solutions are discouraged as a rule.

Comment: @biziclop: yes, i was planning to do HMACs to verify messages anyways. but i need to establish a symmetrics key first which is know to both sides. also, i am not implementing a lot of hand-rolled security things here ... the encryption and signing things are all pretty much standard fare.

Comment: @biziclop: also - why would i need the challenge-response if i send the initial packet signed with by the client and encrypted with the public key of the "server" and let the server reply with a session key signed by the server and encrypted with the public key of the client? if, on top of that, the client has to include a timestamp and nonce, the server can verify that the timestamp is within a reasonable timeframe, and it could also verify that the nonce is unique (although, it would have to keep a list of "seen" nonces ... )

Comment: @rmalchow As I said, timestamps are useless for this purpose. Challenge-response is only to establish that it is a genuine client and not someone replaying a packet sent by a client earlier. If you don't care about that (given that all you do afterwards is send out a session key, you may choose to do so), you don't need the challenge-response step.